# Various issues with low poly hammer

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, topology

I have about 4 weeks of Blender knowledge.

Why is the line shown in the Bottom red circle not affected by the *Subdiv* modifier? It feels like it should be, but it leaves a sharp edge? I can't make sense of it.

[image]

Secondly. I want to keep the triangle shape shown in blue (top image), but from what I understand I have to turn all my faces into quads. My first solution is shown in the bottom image, but if I take that route I lose the triangular corner and introduce all sorts of wackiness when it comes to edge loops. Is there a simple solution?

The other highlighted problems are minor: There's a weird hitch in the edge shown in the top red circle which I can't solve without breaking something else. I'd also like to move the edge shown by the dotted black line to the yellow line, but, again, as soon as I attempt it, the models turns into a horror show.

[.Blend files on Gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iLvMQe3Wi1tEZevoj_QlTy4gHtJMXJlC/view?usp=sharing) [1.6mb] (Pre and post edge looped) with references images if anyone's feeling extra charitable.

[Link to the reference images I'm using on flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/35604059@N03/9452238622/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mirrors for project files (`squiddy-hammer.zip`): [catbox.moe](https://files.catbox.moe/ibssly.zip), [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220426211558if_/https://files.catbox.moe/ibssly.zip)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have adjacent faces but they are actually separate, so it cuts the effect of the *Subdivision Surface*, see:

[image]

or:

[image]

You need to join these faces:

[image]

and:

[image]

As for the tri, in my opinion you can keep tris as long as the faces render correctly. Here you can bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) all the edges that are supposed to stay sharp. First select the edges that are supposed to be sharp, in your case switch to *Edge Select* in order to avoid the selection of the vertical edges along the handle:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are amazing! How do you answer all these questions so fast and so thoroughly?

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 Nobody knows and we're too afraid to ask...

Comment: This is exactly the type of instruction I needed - many thanks! I'll edit my question to include a reference image. I do want to keep that sharp edge on the top, but I'm still interested in how you were able to split the edge like that. To be honest, a lot of what you did sort of looks like magic to me, ha, but I'll study it the best I can and try to put it into practice. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Making use of the bevel operation in this way wouldn't have occurred to me, so I'm again in your debt!

Comment: well, it's pretty simple, I am a prisoner of the Blender foundation and they force me to answer  :/  but they told me that maybe they will set me free at 100k reputation  :)

Comment: Ha! Well, keep up the good work! ;D

Comment: @moonboots I'm obviously misapprehending something. When I try to bevel the edges I want to keep sharp, the original line is lost and I wind up with something that looks very different https://postimg.cc/Sn9GvwLX .  Are you only using the bevel on the tri and utilising edge loops elsewhere?

Comment: see my edit, I hope it helps

Comment: @moonboots Yes! That did the trick! Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a lot of questions about keeping edges sharp, so I wanted to add this quick and easy trick.

One way to keep an edge sharp on a subdivided surface is to mark it as a crease.

Press 2 for edge select, select the edges you want, then press shift+E, type 1 then enter. The edge will turn purple and will no longer be effected by the subdivision.

This can have odd effects depending on the state of the surrounding geometry, but it is a much simpler alternative to bevel.

Comment: Thanks for the additional response. Definitely something I'll investigate!